# Send Xiaomi thermometer data to server endpoint

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, xiaomi

I would like to connect to my Xiaomi bluetooth thermometer, read it's data periodically and send it to some API endpoint over the network.

First solution that came to my mind was native mobile app development (Android OS) which would the job but requires quite some work and I am also unsure if it's possible to connect to this particular device. Another idea was to look for general purpose app designed for connecting to bluetooth device and reading it's data yet I did not find one on Google Play store.

Is there any way to share thermometer readings over the internet without spending money on arduino for instance or any other additional components? Maybe Xamarin is a way to go to speed up mobile app development for this purpose?

Comment: you need to check that thermometer's documentation of how you can read the data from it.

Comment: And a quick search shows a number of possible implementations including this one: https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2019/09/mijia-ble.html which has source code: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MijiaScanner

Comment: I accidentally found a solution to my problem. It appears that there is Mijia Temp app which connects to thermometer and is also capable of sending data to ThingSpeak for remote monitoring. I was looking for Xiaomi related apps all this time instead of Mijia. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smrtprjcts.mijiabt